# Wrong projectile flight

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

When I try to make a projectile fly, it flies and turns in the same direction as the object that turns.
That is, the projectile flew out, the object turns further and the projectile begins to turn after it.

It is necessary that the projectile fly regardless of the rotation of the object, but at the same time in the right direction and at 45 degrees down.

The projectile itself has nothing to do with the object being rotated and is not located inside this object, which is rotated by `Rotation.Y`.

```
using UnityEngine;
public sealed class Bullet : MonoBehaviour {
    private readonly float Speed = 30;
    private Vector3 Position;
    public Transform ObjectTransform; // an object that is in the air and is rotated by Y.

    void Start() {
        transform.localRotation = Quaternion.identity;
        Position = transform.position;
    }
    void Update() {
        transform.eulerAngles = new(45, ObjectTransform.eulerAngles.y, 0);
        transform.Translate(Speed * Time.deltaTime * Vector3.forward);
        if (Physics.Linecast(Position, transform.position, out RaycastHit Hit)) {
           gameObject.SetActive(false);
           transform.localPosition = transform.eulerAngles = Vector3.zero;
        }
        Position = transform.position;
    }
}
```

Help me to understand.

Comment: Not to sure what you mean by it turns when the object turns (what object? the projectile? the target? the weapon? lol), but it sounds like the projectile might be influenced by a parent object. Is it the child of another object? If so, just unparent the projectile.

Comment: Normally a bullet would follow a ballistic trajectory. If it is some type of guided missile it should be directed towards the target (or the predicted impact point). In either case it would be common to just have the projectile rotated to have the front in the travel direction. Copying the targets rotation to the bullet makes no sense to me. If you shoot someone facing you, should the bullet point toward the shooter?

Comment: @DylanT25, Read the question before commenting on what is already written in the question. What difference does it make which object? Rotates on the Y axis. Even wrote about it, which changes on `Rotation.Y`. And he also wrote that it does not apply and is not enclosed. And so he wrote that it is necessary to always fly out and fly at 45 degrees. How much clearer?

Comment: @JonasH, Nothing points to anyone, the object hangs in the air, spins and a bullet flies out from its front part, which must always fly at 45 degrees simply along a downward trajectory. The bullet is outside this object and spawns at the desired point without being added to the object.

Comment: @JonsH, `ObjectTransform.eulerAngles.y` - I understand the campaign - this is a dynamically changing part - the bullet flies, and this also always changes, since the object is spinning and this is why such a problem occurs. How to fix it?

Comment: @Uncer, The only reason I asked for clarity on the object, was so I could better visualise what was happening in the game - and hopefully help find a solution. I was thinking that the projectile was coming from something like a rocket launcher, which led me to think it was shooting in an arch, and the downards arc was problematic. I see in your comment to JonasH you explained that the object shooting hangs in the air, which makes it a lot clearer for myself and others - and that is how we can solve a problem as a community. If you don't want to troubleshoot with people don't ask for help.

Comment: @DylanT25, Ok, then how to solve the problem itself?